# Regex: Do not match string with words preceding target word

Tags: python, regex

How do I find a regex match for a target word, but if that target word is preceded by a negation word (like 'not') it does not give a match.

The negation word needs to be within a certain range before the target word so it does not look back too far for another negation

**Example:**

```
Target = 'word'

+------------------------------------------+-------------+
| 'bananas is a word'                      | match       |
| '76 is not a word'                       | NOT a match |
| '76 is not a word but bananas is a word' | match       |
+------------------------------------------+-------------+
```

**Note:**

`'76 is not a word but bananas is a word'` contains **not** but **is** a match. This is why I cannot use `^$`.

Ideally I would be able to include multiple negation words so the regex would look something like:

```
.{1,25}(?<!(isn't|not).{1,10}) word
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what is the result?

Answer (score 0):

If the pattern is always going to be along the lines of the following:

```
bananas is a word
76 is not a word
76 is not a word but bananas is a word
bananas is a word but 76 is not a word
bananas is a word and bird is a word
76 is not a word and 86 isn't a word either
```

then you can use the following regex:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\sis(?!'nt|\snot)\sa\sword
```

Note the use of both a capturing and non-capturing group, to ensure that `isn't` and `is not` are properly excluded from matches.

[Fiddle in Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/pUxXzP/1/)